# How to handle unobserved exceptions in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am specifically asking about how to handle unobserved exceptions, not unhandled exceptions. This question is also different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502745/746754) which is asking about how to raise fire-and-forget async methods, not about how to handle unobserved exceptions, though they are related.

Unobserved exceptions are the type that are caused by the example shown below, taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx?PageIndex=2&wa=wsignin1.0#comments):

```
Task op1 = FooAsync(); 
Task op2 = BarAsync(); 
await op1; 
await op2;
```

As a rule I try to avoid this situation, but if it should occur I don't want my web site to exit unexpectedly and I don't want these exceptions to be swallowed silently. I at least want to handle them in one place and log them. I don't want to use elmah.

Now, I think that we can do something like this example from [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/22/eduasync-part-12-observing-all-exceptions.aspx):

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, e) => 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Saving the day! This exception would have been unobserved: {0}", 
                      e.Exception); 
    e.SetObserved(); 
};
```

But, my questions are: -

- Where to put this, can it go in Application_Start()?
- Will these unobserved exceptions make their way into Application_Error()? If so, how do you identity them or prevent them from turning up in Application_Error.

[This question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1775799.aspx/1?RE%20example%20to%20show%20how%20to%20use%20taskscheduler%20unobservedtaskexception%20event%20plus%20) is similar, but there is no satisfactory answer / explanation.

Comment: see   [this][1] link how they handle unobserved exception 

  [1]: https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler/blob/master/FluentScheduler.Webtester/Global.asax.cs

Comment: Actually, that link refers to libraries that I don't have access to. However, my UnobservedTaskException code above does work.