# Run async function from sync as well as Async function c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am sending 'Async' emails.

I use a common 'Async' function to call the Email function as I don't need to wait for the response for the emails.

```
public Task SendAsync(....)
{
      ....
      return mailClient.SendMailAsync(email);
}
```

I need to call it from both `async` and `sync` functions.

**Calling from async function**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncFunction(...)
{
   ....
   EmailClass.SendAsync(...);
   ....
   // gives runtime error.
   // "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending..."
   // Solved by using 'await EmailClass.SendAsync(...);'
}
```

**Calling from sync function**

```
public ActionResult syncFunction(...)
{
   ....
   EmailClass.SendAsync(...);
   ....
   // gives runtime error. 
   // "An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time..."
   // Solved by converting the function as above function
}
```

Both the functions give runtime error which is then solved by using `await` keyword in async function.

But by using `await` it defeats my purpose of `running it on background without waiting for response`.

How do i call the async function without waiting for the response?

Comment: Your fundamental problem is the misunderstanding that the benefit of writing asynchronous code in this context is to fire and forget - that's not the primary intention of this kind of asyncrony, which is to free up threads while you *wait* for the tasks' completion - not to simply not bother waiting for it.

Comment: Yep, i think i understand that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

A) Create a 'Fire and Forget' request, as you are trying to do.

or

B) Await the result of your request async.

Method A will use 2 threads, the first being your request thread and the second would be the fire and forget thread. This would steal a thread from the request threadpool, causing thread starvation under heavy load.

Method B will spend 1 thread when there are things to process.. the request thread that is.

Method B will consume less resources, and while Method A potentially could be a few ms faster, but at the price of a thread(read: expensive!).

When using Async/await, the thread is only active when doing CPU work, and is freed up to serve other requests/tasks when doing IO-bound work.

While initiating a new thread, will block that thread until it is done (unless you wanna do some complicated thread synchronization).

**TL;DR** : Async/Await is way more efficient, and you will end up starving your webserver, if you choose to use Fire and Forget.

If you still want to run background tasks, [read this blog post: Search Results
How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET - Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: Isn't the method B what i am currently doing?

Comment: @PatrickHofman true, but if he wants his request to return immediatly, a new thread will have to be fired up.

Comment: @Ruchan Yes, method B is your async/await you were already doing.

Comment: can anyone explain why i have to use `await`?

Comment: The ASP.NET runtime is telling you that you are probably making a mistake. Returning the request before the work is finished, doesn't really make sense, unless you specifically specify that you want this to run as a background task. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502745/fire-and-forget-async-method-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Ruchan Glad I could be of help :)