# SendOrPostCallback behaviour

Tags: c#

**SendOrPostCallback** Represents a method to be called when a message is to be dispatched to a synchronization context. In first case SendOrPostCallback points on async method that i guess should be executed synchronously. What will happen if Delegate will point on async delegate? How behaviour should change?

Before changes:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(SomeMethods), null);
    }

    private async void SomeMethods(object obj)
    {
        await Foo(obj);
    }

    private async Task Foo(object obj)
    {
        bool Canceled = false;
        while (!Canceled)
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

After changes:

```
public class ViewModelImproved
{
    public ViewModelImproved()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(async (obj) => { await SomeMethods(obj); }), null);
    }

    private async Task SomeMethods(object obj)
    {
        await Foo(obj);
    }

    private async Task Foo(object obj)
    {
        bool Canceled = false;
        while (!Canceled)
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: `async` is not a part of a method signature. `SendOrPostCallback` is a `delegate void`, so the async method you pass will be called in the [fire-and-forget mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502745/11683).

Comment: @GSerg,if i understand correct in both cases will be the same execution behaviour? Fire and forget in first case and in second also?

Comment: Yes, because the outer method is still `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no substantial difference. In the first code, there's an `async void`, and in the second code, there's an `async void`. In the second code, the `async void` is hidden within a lambda expression.

Generally, you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In this particular case, it may be OK, since you're dealing with a UI context.